# how to use jQuery $.post() Method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

i am trying to call a method of a controller which method will not return anything but it will process the data.
my jquery method is like

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").on("click", function(){
        var number = $("#ID").val();
        $.post("<?php echo site_url('promo/getinfobyid()'); ?>", {id: number});

    });});
```

and my controller method is like

```
public function getinfobyid()
    {
        //$id=$_POST['id'];
        echo 'Selected '.$id;

    }
```

how i will get the data in getinfobyid()??

Answer (score 1):

First of all why are you calling controller function like that

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('promo/getinfobyid()'); ?>", {id: number});
```

I mean you can try like this

```
$.post("promo/getinfobyid", {id: number});
```

Or your case maybe you have written code in JavaScript script tag but you can do like this

```
$.post("<?php echo site_url('promo/getinfobyid'); ?>", {id: number});
```

Check there is no brackets added.

Comment: and how i get my data in getinfobyid ??

Comment: Well you can use codeigniters in build function using $this->input->post('test'); // $_POST['test'] like this

Comment: tried ...but somehow getinfobyid can't be called :(

Comment: @mishir.ali have you removed index.php from your controller/action call if yes then you also have to add that one in URL & it will be _<?php echo site_url('index.php/promo/getinfobyid'); ?>_

Comment: done....it was working but only be shown when there is a callback function in post.... tnx :)

Comment: but it's showing the same value even if i select the different image...!! can you tell me how to get current value of selected image @rajesh  ??

Comment: See I don't what code you have written .on the basis of your above code I just can advice you about passing values to controller function ..